# Migrating Oracle Forms Application to Oracle Apex - POC

Tags: oracle-apex, oracleforms

As part of a Proof of Concept we are looking to migrate a complex Oracle Forms 10g Application into Oracle Apex 5.1(or later versions.) The Oracle Forms applications interfaces many peripheral devices via calls using WEBUTIL_C_API built in.
Is there a similar equivalent built in function for Oracle Apex?
The WEBUTIL_C_API is used to call external C dll libraries.
This will be very helpful to use in Oracle APEX.
Also if there are any working examples of ORACLE APEX talking to peripheral devices like ECD Cash drawers, label printers, EFTPOS terminals etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cannot run C code or library from APEX, though you can do it from Forms.

With APEX, you'll have to run your C code from the database using "[external procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DFSIG/external-procedures.htm#DFSIG-GUID-C61A9DAF-FE6B-4B0E-B6D7-BA61B0ECE0D6)" (check `CREATE LIBRARY` instruction).

You can then run the PL/SQL procedure that wraps the C code from APEX.